# How to double data in DF

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I want to double my data frames data, currently it reads:

```
  x1  x2
1  1   6
2  2   7
3  3   8
4  4   9
5  5   10
```

from:

```
x <- matrix(1:10, ncol =2)

df <- data.frame(x)
```

I have found an example online that will double the data, however I don't want the data doubled row by row, I want it doubled as a whole.

Example code:

```
df <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), each=2),]
```

This will produce:

```
  x1  x2
1  1   6
1  1   6
2  2   7
2  2   7
ETC
```

What I want is this:

```
  x1  x2
1  1   6
2  2   7
3  3   8
4  4   9
5  5   10
1  1   6
2  2   7
3  3   8
4  4   9
5  5   10
```

Cheers,

Comment: You want `df[rep(1:nrow(df), times=2), ]` (not `each=2`), but you don't need to name it either ...  `df[rep(1:nrow(df), 2),]`.  Also, you could just do `rbind(df, df)`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go through the following solution:

```
x <- matrix(1:10, ncol =2)
df <- data.frame(x)
```

Now, combine `df` using `rbind` operation as shown below:

```
rbind(df,df)
     X1 X2
  1   1  6
  2   2  7
  3   3  8
  4   4  9
  5   5 10
  6   1  6
  7   2  7
  8   3  8
  9   4  9
  10  5 10
```

Hope it works for you!